# Search replace string pattern add px to numeric value

Tags: html, css, linux, search, str-replace

I'm trying to add px after a random numeric value.

This will be done on a CentOS server and needs to be done recursively for all .htm extensions.

a similar example would be

```
<br>style="position:absolute;top:1103;left:459"><br>
```

to

```
style="position:absolute;top:1103px;left:459px">
```

The common pattern would be `'style="position:absolute;top:#;left:#">'`

How can i do this ?

Comment: It will be automatically added by the browser if you specify style='width:10'. If you want to add manually after creating the file , u need regex to do it.

Comment: There are many text editors which come with powerful regex replace. just open your file in that editor and run to function to add "px" wherever needed. I recommend Sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery script

JS:

```
var s = $('.container').attr('style');
var arr = s.split(':');    
for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
{
    if(!isNaN(arr[i]))
    {
        arr[i] += 'px';
    }
}
var new_style = arr.join(':');
$('.container').attr('style', new_style);
```

**UPDATE**:

Used the split function twice.

JS :

```
        var s = $('.container').attr('style');
        var arr = s.split(';');    
        for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
        {

            var temp = arr[i].split(':');
            if(!isNaN(temp[1]))
            {
                temp[1] += 'px';
            }
            arr[i] = temp.join(':');
        }
        var new_style = arr.join(';');
        $('.container').attr('style', new_style);
        $('.container').html('Style = '+ new_style);
```

[Updated DEMO link](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/UctsG/)

Comment: Nice work Karan. My question is that why do we need to add through a  function when it ll be added automatically. Don't just say that OP asks

Comment: That almost got it.  It added the px to the left value, but not the top.  Could you please provide the answer for the top.